# What design pattern to use for collection of items?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am trying to make this example as natural as possible to make it simple.

Lets say I have groups of items. eg item1, item2, item3, item4 etc.

Currently `item` is represented by struct:

```
// only contains data
struct item{
  string name;
  std::vector<string> parts_name;
  std::vector<double> parts_price;
  std::vector<string> item_color;
  ...
};
```

itemx item1, item2...

Then I have class called `items`

```
class items{
  public:
  // return name of all items
  vector<string> get_all_item();

  // return price of all parts 
  vector<double> get_all_parts_price();  

 private:
  // hold vector of item
  vector<shared_ptr<item>> list_of_items;

  // name of item and its parts price
  // eg: <item_1_part_1, $1.3>
  // eg: <item_1_part_2, $2.3>
  // eg: <item_2_part_1, $4.3>
  map<string, double>  parts_prices;
};
```

The problem with my current items class is that it is growing really huge, 
as feature of item increases.

My solution: make struct item contain function which distributes load 
to struct item from class items.

Is there any other better way or any design pattern that is meant for this kind of problem?

Comment: Probably just use a `std::vector<item>`

Comment: You should probably not return copies of vector... Simply store everything in `std::vector<item>` as mentioned by @Justin, `get_all_items()` returns a `(const) std::vector<item>&` and for the various part you can just create custom iterators that iterate over items and "sub"-vectors, this way you never have to create vector when you simply need to read something...

Comment: what does `get_all_parts_price()` want to return? The sum of all prices of all parts, or a list of prices and parts?

Comment: @RichardHodges  list of prices of all the parts present in all the items .. basically all the value of parts_prices.

Comment: Why is color a vector?  Why do items have both parts and their price?  Why does items return a vector of prices, when each item has a vector of prices?  What is item, and what does it represent in comparison to parts?  You are doing OO design and asking for help, without describing what the objects *are*.  Why are parts not items, what distinguishes them, and why do parts exist?

Comment: The longer I read your question and your comment, the less I understand. I think you **seriously** want to step back and A) think hard about your domain, the objects, ... B) improve your question. You can't even *communicate* your model. That is a symptom of that model being overly complicated/out of place/...

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell you how to "design" your application based on your input - and I think you are focusing on the wrong aspect here. Your item struct contains vectors. That implies **plural**. But still, the class is called `item`.

In that sense: don't think about patterns here. Instead, step back and have a much closer look at the "real world things" you intend to model. You see, the core point of objects and classes is to built a *model* of the *domain* you are dealing with.

So a non-answer here: carefully look into the "real-world" relation that your objects have, and then *focus* on creating a OO model that is helpful  to do work flows you intend to implement.

Comment: How coincidental! Here's an example of a domain model I just did for another question similar to this one in the sense that patterns are probably not needed! https://stackoverflow.com/a/45224011/1168342

Comment: Nice, even with UML ;-)