# Discussion: Which design patterns would you use for this solution?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

I would like to design software that has the following solution:

- Products *have* features.
- Each products has rules for features:

  - *Product* must have *features* `a,b and d`.
    _ *Product* must have at least x of list of features `f,g and m`
    _ Each *feature* of product has a weight.
- At runtime I'd like to create *products* using, from external input (file/user input) and add *features* to the product with *rules*.
- I'd like ask each *product*, given the *features* it's been fed, what score it has and what's missing.

Let me illustrate the last point:
Let's say *product* `A` has rules regarding must have features `a and b`, must have at least 2 of `c, d, e and f` and could also have (but not must) features `g, h ,i and j`.
I've also assigned the following weights `a,b each equal 5`, `c, d, e and f each equal 10` and `g, h ,i and j each equal 2.5`. (all in all 60 points)
Case 1:
*Product*  `a` of type `A` has features `a, c, d, h, j`. I'd like the following report:
Is not A because missing `b`. Score = 0.5 ( (5 + 10 + 10 + 2.5 + 2.5) / 60 )
Can also receive `b, e, f, g, i`

Case 2:
*Product*  `b` of type `A` has features `a, b, c, e, h, j`. I'd like the following report:
Is A. Score = 0.5833 ( (5 + 5 + 10 + 10 + 2.5 + 2.5) / 60 )
Can also receive `d, f, g, i`

Here's what I've come up so far:

- The `Products` and `Features` should be created by a `factory` so they can be generated at runtime and follow the same interface.
- Reports should be generated using the `strategy` pattern.

What would you recommend?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the requirement that makes Strategy pattern for reports necessary. It seems like it's the same logic, just two results are different. Score is calculated the same way. The results in the report seem to be the same format.

Answer (score 3):

A domain model is useful (I think I got it right based on your text):

[image]

From there, I don't see enough variations in design (e.g., Product `A` is just an *instance* of the `Product` class, Feature `a` is just an *instance* of the `Feature` class) to justify patterns. Not even a Factory is needed, IMO. Am I missing something from your question?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand that you got object who run the same logic (reports, scores and missing features). But you got different settings for each object, product A don't have the same settings than product B.

Then I think you can check the design pattern template : https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method

It can help you to define the different rules of your product.

Comment: Template method would apply to which class? What algorithm is decomposed? The rules seem to be about "must have" or "could have" and so I don't see enough variation to justify template method. If the requirements said "we want to allow defining of arbitrary rules later" then maybe it's the case, but again you'd have to assume some dimension of the variation in the rules, e.g., rules about weight, rules about numbers of items (no more than 5), etc. None of that is specified in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that there will be text input for product e.g. A,a,c,d,h,j for case 1. Using Static factory for Products is good approach. Using strategy for Report generation is not correct. If your context for strategy is product then do you have a use case where Product-A at run time changes to Product-B? I guess NO. (Strategy is used when without changing State there is family of algorithms and its interchangeable). Here Products will contain different combinations of rules and features and hence state changes (No Strategy). I guess no additional design pattern is required.

Following OO design will work.
Abstract-Product contains Collection of Rules which is filled up in Concrete Product constructor. Abstract-Product also contains Collection of Features which is filled up while parsing ext data input String.

Feature is modeled as an enum with weight as param.

Rule is modeled as abstract class with abstract "boolean check()" which concrete rules override. concrete Rule requires product to access its collection of features, hence product to rules is bidirectional association.

When concrete product is configured from ext input String though static factory, we call generateReport() method which iterates over all rules in collection. each rule applies the rule and updates the violation String (if violated) with its specific message (part) (e.g. feature b is absent etc). generateReport() in ConcreteProduct makes consolidation of report message taking in to account violation messages.

Similar approach for weight computation as its only dependent upon the features.
So I guess only Static Factory is enough as a design pattern. Features can be instatiated by enum.ValueOf().

Here I suppose indirectly we will be using Bridge Design pattern between Product Hierarchy and Rule Hirrarchy by implementing generateReport() with the help of check() in Rule.